# How can I use BLE notifications in Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working with `sensorTags` and `LightBlue Beans BLE` devices, but can not find a way to interact with them using notifications. I have tried several codes in python which implements read/writes but I need to speedup the access to the sensors data. Any suggestion? I'm using a raspberry based platform and python.

Comment: How are you talking to the BLE device, using `bluez`?

Comment: You really need to add some example code and be more specific about what you've already implemented.  As Python doesn't yet have support for BLE type sockets, I'm curious how you're working around that.

Answer (score 1):

You will have an easier time using Node.js, these are actively worked on.

For Central devices: https://github.com/sandeepmistry/noble

For Peripheral devices: https://github.com/sandeepmistry/bleno

Answer (score 0):

This Gist shows how to use python-dbus to read out scratch characteristics data: https://gist.github.com/jsiverskog/0afa43225bdbe8e803cb

From my tests it seems to be quick to react on updates in the data (of course somewhat dependent on your actual implementation on the Bean). It should provide enough information to get you going.